# Are these equations correct? (transfer function)

Tags: transfer-function, decibel

I have a given transfer function \$ |H| = \frac{R_2}{\sqrt{R_1^2+\frac{1}{(\omega c)^2}}} \$
 where \$ c = 1\mathrm{\mu F} \$ and \$ R_1,R_2 \$ are unknown. 
I know that \$ |H(j\omega_c)| = 50.1 \$ where 
\$ \omega_c = 500\mathrm{ rad/s} \$ and that the gain decreases with 20dB/decade for \$\omega<\omega_c\$. The way I've understood the 20dB/decade decrease is that for \$\omega=50\mathrm{rad/s}\$ we should have 
\$|H|_{dB}=14 \implies |H|=5.012\$ since
 \$50.1\approx 34\mathrm{dB}\$. By that reasoning I get the following two equations

$$
\frac{R_2}{\sqrt{R_1^2+\frac{1}{(500c)^2}}}=50.1\
$$
and
$$
\frac{R_2}{\sqrt{R_1^2+\frac{1}{(50c)^2}}}=5.012\
$$

But they don't give me the right answers, what is wrong with this reasoning?

Here is the schematic 
[image: Here is the schematic]

Comment: Please take a look at the appearance of your question. It is almost unreadable...can you fix it?

Comment: I'm sure he'll be back LOL

Comment: okay fixed it!! hopefully it's better now

Comment: BTW what sort of high-pass filter circuit is the TF for?

Comment: **No one** can tell you if the equations are correct since it is **unclear** what they apply to. You have to include a schematic.

Comment: It's a simple active high pass filter!

Comment: I was just wondering if the reasoning was correct or not. If I know the gain for a certain frequency and that it increases by 20dB/decade up until that point then would it be correct to insert the frequency one decade down and have the gain decrease by 20 dB? To me it sounds correct, maybe my execution wasn't? I didn't want to include the schematic because I didn't want that to draw attention from my question but I can add it if it helps!

Comment: If I'm given the information that the gain increases by 20dB/decade for frequencies lower than \$\omega_c=500\mathrm{rad/s}\$ then doesn't that mean that \$|H(j50\mathrm{rad/s})|=5.012\$ if I know that \$H(j\omega_c)|=50,1\$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to say, given the way you formulated your question, but since you are given the corner frequency \$\omega_c=500\$, then you know that the transfer function -- which is that of a highpass -- has \$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\$ of the maximum magnitude, so then \$H(j\infty)=50.1\sqrt{2}\approx70.8521\$. This is the ratio of the two resistors. Now you have two equations of two unknowns:

$$\frac{R_2}{R_1}=70.8521$$
$$\frac{R_2}{\sqrt{R_1^2+\frac{1}{(500*1\mu)^2}}}=50.1$$

Which gives \$R_1\approx2\text{k}\Omega\$ and \$R_2\approx141.7042\text{k}\Omega\$. Here's a quick check with LTspice:

[image: test]

The voltage is taken after the second, inverting `E` source (for positive output).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my question is why I can't just insert the frequencies and gains in the transfer function and solve \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ from there. I mean it's a function with two unknowns and I have two frequencies of which I know the value of the function. Something is obviously wrong, but I don't understand what it is

Comment: You are assuming that the gain is the textbook piece-wise linear across the frequency, but it isn't, as shown in the picture above. There is a soft knee around the corner frequency which means you cannot simply consider a decade higher/lower frequency and deduce the gain. You were given the specific point at fc so that you know that the gain is, specifically, 1/sqrt(2) of the total gain. Because it's a highpass and the transfer function is asymptotic, the gain at infinity is the gain set by R2/R1. Only now you have two, solid equations from which you can deduce the rest.